# PR2 move_base how to get map

Tags: gazebo, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I bring up pr2 in Gazebo with

```
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_emtpyworld.launch
```

PR2 comes up and I want to use move_base programatically to move it to some (x,y) coordinate.
So I tried to bring up move_base server with following..

```
rosrun move_base move_base
```

But it asks for map, the tutorials in pr2_simulator and navigation stack only talk about pre-defined maps.

```
[ INFO] [1358441051.857729791]: Subscribed to Topics: 
[ INFO] [1358441051.868857033]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1358441051.870152566]: Still waiting on map...
```

Is it possible to get a map out of Gazebo? Or, am I suppose to be manually creating a map file?
I read similar questions on this forum, but still confused..
Since I am fairly new to ROS/ navigation stack / map, please refer to specific example. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52608/pr2-move_base-how-to-get-map/) by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll need to build a map using SLAM, unless you want to create that by hand.
See, e.g. this tutorial:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/BuildingAMapInSimulation

Other alternatives are to use the /odom frame for navigation, but that will drift over time on a real robot, so you can't drive to a specific x,y then.

However, building a map and localizing in it will only work if there is something in the world, i.e. it won't work for the empty world.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on 2013-01-17**:
Hmm.. So with pr2_empty_world.launch, I will not be able to build a map out of it. Let me try to clarify. So, in order to localize correctly, some objects must be in sight of PR2 when mapping starts. Am I understanding correctly?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-01-17**:
Yes. Actually any empty image will be a correct map for the empty world. Obviously the robot can't localize if there is nothing to recognize.

**Comment by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on 2013-01-17**:
Then, instead of using SLAM, is it somehow possible to use x,y location provided by Gazebo? I want to be complete sync with location coordinate inside Gazebo.. If it is possible, do you know of examples or have rough idea on how to accomplish it? Thanks!

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-01-17**:
For simulation you could use fake localization: http://www.ros.org/wiki/fake_localization

**Comment by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on 2013-01-17**:
That looks great. But still confused.. What is correct step of launching stuff.. I launch pr2_emptyworld and  run fake_localization? Is something missing inbetween? Do you know why fake_localization complains about Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.fake_localization. blah blah